# Исключение Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

Вот код на Java:

```
package com.company;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClients;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.ParseException;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.io.entity.EntityUtils;


public class Main {
    static String sURL = "http://speller.yandex.net/services/spellservice";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        CloseableHttpResponse resp1 = null;
        try{
            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(sURL + "/checkText?text=мошына");
            resp1 = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resp1.getEntity()));
        } catch (IOException | ParseException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                resp1.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Ошибка:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:24)
```

Как исправить данную ошибку?

Comment: Мне кажется, вам будет полезна конструкция try с ресурсами. Потому что не нужно в блоке finally париться с закрытием соединения, и в этом же блоке перехватывать исключения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

на строке 24 вы вызывает метод close() у объекта (resp1) значение которая ровняется null если сработал catch.
Сделайте что то типа:

```
public class Main {
    static String sURL = "http://speller.yandex.net/services/spellservice";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        CloseableHttpResponse resp1 = null;
        try{
            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(sURL + "/checkText?text=мошына");
            resp1 = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resp1.getEntity()));
        } catch (IOException | ParseException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (resp1 != null) {
              try {
                  resp1.close();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Данная ошибка исправлена, но к сожалению появились 2 другие

Comment: @David Естественно. Переменная `resp1` была `null` в `finally`, потому что не произошло присваивание `resp1 = httpClient.execute(httpGet);`. То есть первое исключение - в `httpClient.execute(httpGet);`.

Comment: @Igor так как исправить?

Comment: @David Что исправить? Ошибку, которую Вы нам не скажете?

Comment: @David так как исправить? я ведь показал как

Comment: @FarizMamedow я исправил, код запускается, но от yandex speller возвращается пустое значение

Comment: @David Взгляни что там в логах. У тебя срабатывает исключение

Comment: @FarizMamedow а как сделать так, чтобы yandex speller возвращал исправленное слово?